# how to change the path of a zendframework project

Tags: zend-framework

Hi
I want to set up a zend frame work project in my local system. I have downloaded the files and folder and set up in my local xampp (ie, within htdocs I have created a folder named NFL_021. Here I copied all the files and folders). But I need to change the path to `/NFL_021/www`  e:g, from `/images/site/register-here.png` to `/NFL_021/www/images/site/register-here.png`  It's very difficult to change each and every page. Is there is any easy way to set up this?

Please reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [baseUrl](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.baseurl) view helper would be useful. With this helper you could just specify relative path to your files, e.g.:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl('/images/site/register-here.png'); ?>" />
```